# nlapiSearchRecord returning more than one result

Tags: suitescript

I'm trying to find the specific record type 'invoice' using nlapiSearchRecord, my search filter is by internalid.

```
id = 434343;

var filters = new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', id);

var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');

var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', null , filters , columns);
if(searchResult) {
 for (var i = 0 ; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
   alert('Internal ID: '+searchResult[i].getValue('internalid'));
  };
};
```

The result is very weird for me, it's returning {array} length=16. I'm expecting only one result, what can be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I need to add this filter:

```
nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T');
```